# Является ли вводным "без сомнений"?

Tags: вводные-слова

*Лежала и ждала, пока Алексей Андреевич, а это без сомнений был он, выговорится.*

Это **без сомнений** был он!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Лежала и ждала, пока Алексей Андреевич, а это **без сомнений (= точно)** был он, выговорится. Он же, не давая ей возможности ответить, повёл разговор о том...*

***А это без сомнения был он*** — это вводное предложение, представляющее собой авторское замечание. Падежная форма ***без сомненяй*** занимает позицию обстоятельства и не обособляется. Автор выражает **точное знание всех событий, а не отношение** к сказанному, поэтому здесь нет функции вводного слова.

Answer (score 1):

Слово **без сомнения** — не только вводное, оно может быть также дополнением или обстоятельством:
***Без сомнения*** не может быть ученого.
Он говорил об этом **без сомнения.**

В этом предложении "без сомнений" выступает в роли обстоятельства и его можно заменить на похожие по смыслу наречия: и впрямь, и вправду, конкретно, в точности, определенно, и правда, в самом деле.

Я бы это предложение оформила со вставной конструкцией:
*Лежала и ждала, пока Алексей Андреевич — **а это без сомнений был он** — выговорится.*

Вот предложение с похожим смыслом.
*Тайнописцы знали это, а также и то, что в сомнениях — истина и добро, как в уверенности **без сомнений** — ложь и зло. Не в истине радость плебея, а в вере **без сомнений!*** (А. Ревазян)

[«Без сомнения» — запятая нужна или нет?](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/bez-somneniya.html)